# How to put plots that can be zoomed in and out on R shinydashboards?

Tags: r, zooming, shinydashboard

I have prepared a dashboard using R shinydashboard. It is working fine. However the plots using ggplot2 for zooming cannot be used to zoom on shinydashboard. Although it is working fine with R shiny. Moreover the zoom package is also not working for plots on shinydashboard . Please help. Thanks!

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._

Comment: What kind of a plot is it? You could try [rbokeh](http://hafen.github.io/rbokeh/#background), or [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/).

Comment: plot.ly (via the `plotly` package) makes this really easy by letting you convert `ggplot2` plots with `ggplotly()`, getting you zoom and more. `rbokeh` works too, but you'll need to refactor your plotting code.

Comment: thanks .Btw I could solve it by using dygraphs. It was basic line plots